# How to find out if a file geodatabase was compressed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase

I work with a bunch of file geodatabases and some of them are compressed. I want to find out quickly which ones are and which aren't. The Compress File Geodatabase Data GP tool doesn't seem to have any check before running. I don't want to run File Geodatabase Data GP tool on uncompressed geodatabases though; I just to know whether they are compressed/uncompressed.

I could grab some random feature class / table and try starting editing session to see if it will let me do that (because you can't edit data that is compressed), but am looking for a more elegant solution. Ideally this would be an ArcPy/Python solution which I could use for going over multiple geodatabases.

Comment: Are you looking for an ArcPy, ArcObjects or manual solution?  For ArcPy I think you may be looking at needing to submit an ArcGIS Idea.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I was looking for any solution that would allow me to specify a list of file geodatabases and getting information if they are compressed (and which are not). ArcObjects is my last resort if nothing else would work :)

Comment: W.r.t. compression, this actually occurs at the feature class and table level even though you can choose to compress everything in a file geodatabase i.e. within a file geodatabase you can have some feature classes and tables compressed while others are not so I think you should edit your Question to clarify that you are looking for (preferably) an ArcPy way to determine if a feature class or table is compressed.

Comment: @PolyGeo, done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I know, there is no property to automatically identify compressed file geodatabase with arcgis. But you can see this information in ArcCatalog : A compressed feature class or table has "(compressed)" in the Type column.

For routine check, you can also look for the **.cdf** files inside your .gdb folder using file searching methods (e.g. os.walk() or glob.glob() in Python).

Comment: +1 for checking feature class properties window (works both within ArcCatalog and Catalog window in ArcMap) > General tab. But how have you figured out that compressed file geodatabases would have .cdf files? They do indeed and I now just ran a Python script to iterate over .gdb folders.

Comment: I was expecting .lock files so I opened my .gdb in Explorer. But I've found the difference to be the .cdf for the .gdb I knew. Then I checked by compressing /uncompressing one of my gdb and it validated my hypotheses.