# Opening gdb in QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, connection

I have been given an ESRI gdb file by a vendor.  I can connect it in the usual fashion in QGIS but it only shows a couple of the layers that are contained and they show no entities in them.
Has anyone an answer for what is causing this?
[image]

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? Also, maybe double check that its a File Geodatabase that they have sent you....Also what is the file size of the GDB?

Comment: QGIS 3.16.0, It IS a file Geodatabase and it is 33.2MB.  Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it.  Apparently there is a compressed and uncompressed version of the FGDB.  QGIS requires the uncompressed.

Comment: great news - Mind sharing how you detected that it was a compressed FileGDB?

Comment: The vendor seemed to have run into the issue before.  I don't know if there is any way to tell outwardly other than getting 0 entities showing up.

Comment: I do know that there is a way to check using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro - looks like there might be a solution here   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90886/how-to-find-out-if-a-file-geodatabase-was-compressed